What do C++ for-range loops expand to?
A for loop
for (inital; contition; after) {expression;}

expands to
inital;
while(condition)
{
    expression;
    after;
}

But what does a for-range loop (as below) expand to?
for(T &element : iterable) {expression;}

From what I have been able to find using a debugger, it looks something like
auto __for_range = iterable;
static_assert(std::forward_iterator<decltype(__for_range)>);
auto __for_begin = __for_range.begin();
auto __for_end = __for_range.end();
while (__for_begin < __for_end)
{
    T &element = *_for_begin++;
    expression;
}

But from testing that is not entirely the same. So, what does it expand to?

its all here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for. Usually rather good transcription from the standard, to be sure you can look into the standard itself

cppinsights.io might be of interest. Although its output is very similar to what you found yourself.

btw you got the for loop wrong. You are missing to enclose it in {}, the initial is not accessible in the scope where you write the for loop. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

@463035818_is_not_an_ai, thank you! It seems I was quite close with my guess.

cppinsight is a nice tool, but take it with a grain of salt. I have seen bugs that caused its output to be more confusing than helpful

The first snippet is not entirely correct, it doesn't handle continue; properly. "from testing that is not entirely the same" cppreference has a better version. Where did you get yours from?

@HolyBlackCat I made mine up by stepping through a for-range loop with a debugger.

See cpp insight : https://cppinsights.io/s/39fb6085 (and press play button). Also note that usually the generated assembly is the same as for a "classical" for loop
